# HTTPAPI_ERROR when creating device identity with local python on azure IoT Hub

Tags: python-3.x, azure, device, azure-iot-hub

I want to create/subscribe a new (simulated) device with my local machine in azure IoT Hub.

I am using python 3.6.4 (64bit) on windows7 (64bit) machine and run the code with spyder.

Installed, relevant packages:

- azure-iothub-device-client (1.3.1)
- azure-iothub-service-client (1.3.1)
- spyder (3.2.8)

I followed the steps from here: [CreateDeviceIdentity.py](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-python-getstarted)

The code snipped:

```
import sys
import iothub_service_client

CONNECTION_STRING = "myConnectionString"
DEVICE_ID = "pythonDevice_1"

def print_device_info(title, iothub_device):
    print ( title + ":" )
    print ( "iothubDevice.deviceId = {0}".format(iothub_device.deviceId) )
    print ( "iothubDevice.primaryKey = {0}".format(iothub_device.primaryKey) )
    print ( "iothubDevice.secondaryKey = {0}".format(iothub_device.secondaryKey) )
    print ( "iothubDevice.connectionState = {0}".format(iothub_device.connectionState) )
    print ( "iothubDevice.status = {0}".format(iothub_device.status) )
    print ( "iothubDevice.lastActivityTime = {0}".format(iothub_device.lastActivityTime) )
    print ( "iothubDevice.cloudToDeviceMessageCount = {0}".format(iothub_device.cloudToDeviceMessageCount) )
    print ( "iothubDevice.isManaged = {0}".format(iothub_device.isManaged) )
    print ( "iothubDevice.authMethod = {0}".format(iothub_device.authMethod) )
    print ( "" )

#def iothub_createdevice():
try:
    iothub_registry_manager = iothub_service_client.IoTHubRegistryManager(CONNECTION_STRING)
    primary_key = ""
    secondary_key = ""
    auth_method = iothub_service_client.IoTHubRegistryManagerAuthMethod.SHARED_PRIVATE_KEY
    new_device = iothub_registry_manager.create_device(DEVICE_ID, primary_key, secondary_key, auth_method)
    print_device_info("CreateDevice", new_device)

except iothub_service_client.IoTHubError as iothub_error:
    print ( "Unexpected error {0}".format(iothub_error) )
    #return
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ( "iothub_createdevice stopped" )


'''
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ( "" )
    print ( "Python {0}".format(sys.version) )
    print ( "Creating device using the Azure IoT Hub Service SDK for Python" )
    print ( "" )
    print ( "    Connection string = {0}".format(CONNECTION_STRING) )
    print ( "    Device ID         = {0}".format(DEVICE_ID) )

    iothub_createdevice()
'''
```

If I run this code I always get the error:

> ***Unexpected error IoTHubRegistryManager.create_device, IoTHubRegistryManagerResult.HTTPAPI_ERROR***

I found the (or a similar) error on several pages in the inet but never got a working solution for it. The other code example from the microsoft documentation [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-python-getstarted) (SimulatedDevice.py) works fine.

**addon**:
the error can also be reproduced when running the script by command line. The complete error log:

> Error: Time:Thu Apr  5 08:59:55 2018
>   File:C:\release\iot-sdks-internals\release\python\automation\az
>   iotsdk_pytools\src\c\c-utility\adapters\httpapi_winhttp.c
>   Func:HTTPAPI_Init Line:142 WinHttpOpen failed.
>
> Error: Time:Thu Apr  5 08:59:55 2018
>   File:C:\release\iot-sdks-internals\release\python\automation\aziotsdk_pytools\src\c\c-utility\adapters\httpapi_winhttp.c
>   Func:HTTPAPI_Init Line:142 GetLastError: Falscher Parameter.
>
> Error: Time:Thu Apr  5 08:59:55 2018
>   File:C:\release\iot-sdks-internals\release\python\automation\aziotsdk_pytools\src\c\c-utility\src\httpapiex.c
>   Func:HTTPAPIEX_ExecuteRequest Line:475 unable to recover sending to a
>   working state
>
> Error: Time:Thu Apr  5 08:59:55 2018
>   File:C:\release\iot-sdks-internals\release\python\automation\az
>   iotsdk_pytools\src\c\iothub_service_client\src\iothub_registrymanager.c
>   Func:sendHttpRequestCRUD Line:982 HTTPAPIEX_SAS_ExecuteRequest failed
>   Unexpected error IoTHubRegistryManager.create_device,
>   IoTHubRegistryManagerResult.HTTPAPI_ERROR

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue run the Python script using command line? Also please share the detailed error code with us if it exits, like this out of [memory issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/issues/80)?

Comment: hi, no its no memeory error. Please see my additional entry in the first question tag.

Comment: Based on the error message, the issue is occurred in [HTTPAPI_Init](https://github.com/Azure/azure-c-shared-utility/blob/d6cea0f6b8d857b6a4a6d842defae4e54cd77fd0/adapters/httpapi_winhttp.c#L125L159) function. Did you build the python SDK for Azure Iot yourself or just download it via pip?  What's that line of code? To narrow down this issue, I also suggest that you try to create a device identity using other language SDK( eg. .Net) to see whether the issue is relative to environment or specific SDK.

Comment: I downloaded and installed the two azure-iot packages via pip. But I also doanloaded the SDK from git but was not able to build it by ...\azure-iot-sdk-python\build_all\windows\build_client.cmd. On a raspberry pi I was able to build it an created a iothub_client.so. But same error as above (HTTPAPI_ERROR) when running the iothub_registrymanager_sample.py or CreateDeviceIdentity.py. The other sampleCode (iothub_client_sample.py or SimulatedDevice.py) still works fine on both systems. Running the sample code for c-sharp works.

Comment: This issue already fixed in the [latest version SDK(1.3.3)](https://pypi.org/project/azure-iothub-service-client/). Please let me know whether it works for you.

Comment: thank you for the hint! --> updated both pip libraries. code above works directly. Do you know if it works on a linux system (like rsp pi) as well (only by installing the pip packages - without compilation a .so file from the SDK) ?

Comment: Yes,  it should also works. However, base on my understanding we should use the azure-iothub-service-client library on the back-end service instead of client-side(on a device).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, I also got the same error that you got. The solution is uninstall both of the pip packages and install the updated version. If you run the sample code, it is supposed to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is old by now, but I keep running into similar stuff and wanted to share some solutions I've found.

I had this same problem with the newest pip installs (1.4.5) and python3.7 and diagnosed it to incorrect openssl / curl libraries. I resolved it by compiling the Azure IOTHub Python SDK myself, which creates .so files for the device and service clients that you can just drop in your code directory next to your python files.

Here's how I tracked it down:

1. Use pip to find the directory for the module:

   ```
   pip3 show azure-iothub-service-client
   ```
2. This pointed me to /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages. Underneath that was the folder the import uses - /iothub_service_client. I used Apple's 'otool' utility to list the libraries that the service client calls (this can be done on linux using 'ldd'):

   ```
   otool -L /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/iothub_service_client/iothub_service_client.so
   ```
3. That showed me that the library was using the libcurl that comes with MacOSX:

   ```
   /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/iothub_service_client/iothub_service_client.so:
       @rpath/iothub_service_client.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
       /usr/local/opt/boost-python3/lib/libboost_python37-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
       /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python (compatibility version 3.7.0, current version 3.7.0)
       /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 9.0.0)
       /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1452.23.0)
       /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 897.15.0)
       /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.0)
       /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.50.4)
       /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1452.23.0)
   ```

I remembered something about the new MacOS LibreSSL-based curl not working for the MSFT clients, and even though I had my brew-installed curl library directory set in a DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable, I decided to compile the iothub service & device clients myself to see if it fixed the problem. I largely followed the suggestions at https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/doc/python-devbox-setup.md.

Some additional things I did to ensure a successful compile:

1. First, get brew info for curl & openssl using `brew info <package>`
2. The brew versions of curl and openssl were already in my path. They shouldn't be required for a compile, but I've had other setup scripts fail because of version checks against curl and openssl, so they may be needed for the staging scripts. `brew info` gives you the commands you need to put them into your path. It'll be something like:

   ```
   echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
   echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
   ```
3. Make sure the build will use your libs and includes for curl and openssl:

   ```
   export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/curl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
   export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/curl/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
   ```
4. Since these SDKs use Boost, you need to get that installed properly. I finally found the right command to install boost and boost-python for python3 without it installing python2 and dragging in a ton of extra stuff:

   ```
   brew install boost-python3 --with-python3 --without-python
   ```

Once all that is good, you should be able to compile the clients with no problems. The latest version of the SDK has support for Python 3.7, and for the first time in a year, I had an error-free compile on first go. :D

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run this code without a problem.  Can you confirm if your IoT Hub is working properly?  Did you copy the IoT Hub connection string instead of a device connection string?

[image]

Comment: ok, I see. Perhaps there are some restrictions on my machine made by my company (I dont know). The example code above does not work on my machine and not at a colleagues one (always same error). I found a workaround using paho mqtt for handling the traffic and use the REST API to register devices etc. This solution works totally without any azure-iothub -packages or sdk so it also might be running on a raspberry pi too

Comment: @eid , is your machine in proxy environment?

Comment: thank you for your comment. I am not sure if my company uses a proxy. Please see the comments above - the problem should be solved by updating the libraries from 1.3.1 to 1.3.3